# I am Trying to Post Data Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

[image: Our problem with angular and backend]

Hi, thank you for reading this, I have a problem with angular again... The problem is so complicated and I have search in google and also in this forum but until now no answer are solving my problem, so here is the problem.

I am running a localhost, our goal is to make (if you can see the image above) when the user click "tambahkan", then the blank field above yellow button "lanjutkan" appear the list of the things that the user "tambahkan" via the green button (I hope everyone understand the flow)

The problem is, somehow I am confused about how to defined the data from the list of items, so I can throw it into the field above "lanjutkan", anyone can help me?

Here is the codes:

Index.html (for the fields only, the code are too long that I think there's no need to show all of them here)

```
<div class="container-customscroll">
                                    <div class="content mCustomScrollbar">
                                        <div class="itemcheck" ng-repeat="item in dataItem.stores | regex:'name':alfabet | orderBy: 'name' | filter: searchItem">
                                            <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == ''" ng-model="name"><i class="fa fa-circle silver"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
                      <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '1'" ng-model="name"><i class="fa fa-circle green"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
                      <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '2'" ng-model="name"><i class="fa fa-circle yellow"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
                      <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '3'" ng-model="name"><i class="fa fa-circle pink"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
                                            <div class="right" ng-click="addToCart()"><a>+ Tambahkan</a> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /mCustomScrollbar -->
                                </div><!-- /container-customscroll -->

<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="container-sidebaryellow">
                    <div class="title">Pemeriksaan Ditambahkan</div>
                    <div class="container-customscroll">
                        <div class="content mCustomScrollbar">
                            <div class="item-tambahan ">
                                <div class="item checkuptambahan" ng-repeat="cart in tambahCart">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle pink">{{cart.name}}</i>
                                    <a class="checkuptambahan">x</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /content -->
                    </div><!-- /container-customscroll -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btnyellow">Lanjutkan</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is the angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('pesanlab', []);
app.controller('pesanlabCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    //variabel awal
    $scope.showMe = false;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
    }


    $scope.aksi = "tambah";

    //code untuk mengeluarkan data dari data/item.json
    $scope.dapatkanItem = function(){
    $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data){
      $scope.dataItem = data;
    });
    }

    $scope.dapatkanItem();

    $scope.dapatkanPanel = function(){
    $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data){
      $scope.dataPanel = data;
    });
    }

    $scope.dapatkanPanel();

    $scope.dapatkanPaket = function(){
        $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data){
           $scope.dataPaket = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.dapatkanPaket();

    $scope.addToCart = function(){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/someurl',
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
          },
          data: {
          //  master_code: $scope.name,
            name: $scope.item
          }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
          $scope.tambahkan = data;
        });
        console.log($scope.item)
    }

    $scope.tambahkanCart = function(){
        $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
           $scope.tambahCart = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.tambahkanCart();
    });

    app.filter('regex', function() {
          return function(input, field, regex) {
              var patt = new RegExp(regex);
              var out = [];

              if(input === undefined){
                  return out;
              }
              for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                  if(patt.test(input[i][field]))
                      out.push(input[i]);
              }
            return out;
          };
    });
```

and when the console.log are functioning, it returns as "undefined" and also we are using api in website based (I don't know what it's called), and it returns like this, we are using laravel 5.2 for the back-end

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://dev.pesanlab.com/api/v1/order/cart/add. (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-headers' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much

@ravi, here is the code, I think the comment is not the place for codes:

```
$scope.tambahItem = function(){
      $scope.data = $scope.dataItem.stores;
      $scope.temp = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
      alert($scope.temp.name);
};
```

and this code returns "undefined", do you know how to fix this? also if I take the data from Json it returns object also

Answer (score 0):

CORS should be enabled on the server accepting the request. Your server should say that I am ok with accepting api request from unknown/cross-origin places.

I would suggest you to check that.

And BTW, no need to attach images in case you can express your question generically as it might be against the copyright policy of the organisation you might be working on.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I have discussed with the back end, they said that we can use CORS for "GET" but for "POST" still cannot, do you have any idea? Oh yeah, how about my code? Is there any problem? I still have difficulties when I want to get the data using ng-click... thanks BTW, thank you for the suggestions... I will keep that on mind

Comment: While doing POST, browsers send HTTP OPTION and then POST. So you need to enable CORS for OPTION and POST to do POST. 
Please check that will do. You can check in Network tab of browser dev tools for which is failing, I bet that your OPTION xhr is failing. This will help I am sure

Comment: Hmmm... After I check, I think my xhr server status is 200, so I think it worked, oh yah, another thing if I may ask... Do you know the code for getting the data from method post? I use this code $scope.data = $scope.dataItem.stores;
      $scope.temp = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
      alert($scope.temp.name); but returns undefined

Comment: Ideally you should put all http stuff in a service and use that as a dependency in your controller. $http returns a promise, and promises have a `then` method which take a success and error callbacks. The first parameter of success callback is the return data of post.